# POWERSHELL ADSI Invoke - poor time performance

Tags: powershell

Hello i got this problem. Im using Powershell and ADSI to look on Users/Groups that are set on computer. My script working as it should but i got problem with poor time performance. To check some computer it takes few miliseconds but on others it could be 20-40 seconds. Problem is causing this piece of code `$data4 = $group.Invoke("Members")` . I timed it with `measure-command` and it is causing that big time sink.

Here is my code snippet.

```
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computerName/Administrators"
    $members = @()
    $data4 = $group.Invoke("Members") #<--This is cause of poor time performance
    foreach($item in $data4)
    {
        $members += $item.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $item, $null)
    }
```

Has anybody encountered this or similar problem? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's different between the computers that respond quickly vs. those that are slow?

Comment: Well i dont know. I could read everything but the ones with slow response time i couldnt alter users/groups deleting/adding etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the domain or workgroup name before the computer name. That is, instead of just

```
WinNT://computername/Administrators
```

use

```
WinNT://fabrikam/computername/Administrators
```

I would also recommend appending the class name after the object name to tell ADSI which object type you want; e.g.:

```
WinNT://fabrikam/computername/Administrators,Group
```

Comment: Ok i tested it using WinNT://computername/Administrators,Group with added Group parameter pretty much solved my problem. Thank you